# Powershell - set Json to variable

Tags: json, powershell

So I'm making a MySQL query, and one of the columns is a chunk of json that I want to set a particular subset of info to a variable.  Wondering if I can condense my code a little.  Right now my code is:

```
$data = Query -Query "select * from TABLE where fqdn = 'testhost.mycompany.com'"

$json = $data.request | ConvertFrom-Json
$WhatIreallyWant = $json.build_request
```

Can I condense the last two lines?  `build_request` is part of the request json.

Comment: `$WhatIreallyWant = ($data.request | ConvertFromJson).build_request` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pipeline like this

```
$WhatIWant = $data.request | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty build_request
```

or like suggested by [TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler) in the comments

```
$WhatIWant = ($data.request | ConvertFrom-Json).build_request
```

Comment: Indeed it did.  Thanks!